# Install Ubuntu on external harddrive later use it as internal disk

Tags: installation, usb

i want to install ubuntu on a kind of firewall device, that has no usb-port or other connections except LAN. (I don't want to setup a whole tftp etc). So I decided to install ubuntu on an external USB drive holding the 2,5" harddrive of my firewall. Later I placed the harddrive into my firewall and hoped everything would be fine (note, both are x86 architecture). Unfortunately it is not working, the firewall tells me "DISK BOOT FAILURE". Do you have any idea why this is happening, and how I could fix it?

I suspected a grub problem, but even after mounting the USB harddrive in my running Linux, chrooting in /mnt and reinstalling grub nothing changed.

I would be very happy if you could help me on this one :) 
TIA

Comment: can you tell us which firewall it is?I think important is the boot method of this "computer"-if it is expecting e.g. an EFI loader or sth else then you will have no success with "normal boot configuration"

Comment: Of course, didn't know that was important, it is a StoneGate SG 500 (www.andovercg.com/datasheets/stonesoft-specifications-SG-500.pdf)

Comment: Very unlikely that hardware is supported, even if you got Ubuntu installed to it's drive somehow. It has a 'VIA Samuel 2' processor w/ 128MB RAM, well below recommended minimums for an install. It might be easier to replace the main board with a micro atx board, and go from there. This is not a simple task though. Your device might simply be obsolete, and I see the manufacturer themselves stopped supporting it two years ago. Interesting project though, hope I'm wrong and you get it working.

Comment: thx for your help. I'll go on with my tests. Some bsd will run on it for sure, but would have preferred ubuntu :)

Comment: Steven, you may try Debian, I had it running on 133mhz with 32mb ram Linksys NSLU2

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)